# Finding the multiplicity of eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

> Let $T: V \to V$ for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ be a linear operator whose matrix relative to the standard basis consists of all $1's$. find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$ and their geometric and algebraic multiplicities.

I didn't have much trouble finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, but I am not totally certain on the multiplicities. Here is what I have.

> Let $A$ denote the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis, so $A_{ij} = 1$ for all $i,j$. If $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
> $$Av = \begin{pmatrix} \sum\limits_{i} v_i \\ \vdots \\ \sum\limits_{i} v_i \end{pmatrix} = \lambda v = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda v_1 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda v_n \end{pmatrix}.$$
> So
> $$\sum\limits_{i} v_i = \lambda v_k $$
> for all $k$, so
> $$\lambda v_1 = \lambda v_2 = \ldots = \ldots,$$
> which is true if and only if $\lambda = 0$ or $v_1 = v_2 = \ldots = v_n$. If $\lambda = 0$, then  eigenvectors must satisfy $\sum\limits_{i} v_i = 0$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then eigenvectors must satisfy $v_1 = \ldots = v_n$. Let $t$ equal this common term, then we have $\sum_i t = tn = \lambda t$, so $\lambda = n$.

> So the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 0$, in which case the sum of the eigenvectors must be $0$, and $\lambda_2 = n$, in which case all components of the eigenvector must sum to $1$.

By definition, the algebraic multiplicity is the dimension of the nullspace of $(T - \lambda I)^{\dim V}$ and the geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the nullspace of $T - \lambda I$. I cannot figure out how to compute these from my above work, though.

Comment: If you know that the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ and $n$, then use the fact that the trace of the matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues counted with their multiplicity.

Comment: So this is algebraic multiplicity, right? If so, the trace of $A$ is $1 + \ldots + 1 = n$, so that would require that $\lambda_2 = n$ has multiplicity $1$, but it wouldn't tell me anything about the multiplicity of $0$, right? Since the geometric multiplicity is less than or equal to the algebraic multiplicity, that means that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_2$ can't exceed one. It still wouldn't tell me much about $\lambda_1$, though.

Comment: For the geometric multiplicity of 0, you can use direct computations: you have to solve the equation $v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n=0$. You have $n$ variables for one equation. Can you conclude from there?

Comment: That means I have one leading variable and $n-1$ free variable, so the geometric multiplicity is $n-1$?

Comment: Indeed: $\ker(A)=\mathrm{span}\Big\{(1,-1,0,0\ldots,0,0), (1,0,-1,0,\ldots,0,0),\ldots,(1,0,0,0,\ldots,0,-1)\Big\}$. This was Robert's hint: $\dim(\ker A) = n-\mathrm{rank} A = n-1$.

Comment: Does that mean that the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is also $n-1$?

Comment: Yes indeed, as the trace argument above tells us. In fact, $A$ is diagonlizable and multiplicities coincide.

Comment: Thank you. So for $\lambda = 0$, its geometric multiplicity and algebraic multiplicity is $n-1$. for $\lambda = n$, the geometric and algebraic multiplicity is $1$?

Comment: Exactly. The eigenspace associated to $\lambda=n$ is $\mathrm{span}\big\{(1,1,\ldots,1\big\}$.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Nicolas: Sorry, but I took another look at this, and I think I'm again a bit confused. In the $\lambda = 0$ case, for example, the geometric multiplicity is $\dim(\text{ker}(A)) = n - 1$. But how do I find the dimension of the kernel of $A^n$? Is there a general way to find the dimensions of a matrix power?

Comment: I have not talked about the powers of A. The kernel of a diagonalizable matrix is the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue 0. It can be involved computing this kernel. In the present situation, we can simply argue that the kernel of $A^k$, for any integer $k$, is the kernel of $D^k$ where the diagonal matrix $D$ has entry $n,0,\ldots,0$ (up to a permutation). So the kernel is the same, while in general we only have $\ker(A)\subset\ker(A^k)$ (think about nilpotent matrices).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the matrix has rank $1$.

Comment: So if the matrix has rank $1$, then its kernel has dimension $n-1$ by the rank-nullity theorem, but how do I relate this back to multiplicities?

Comment: The (geometric) multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ is the dimension of ...